# Select index values greater than a given time

Tags: python, pandas

Is there something similar to *indexer_between_time* with no end time argument? E.g. get all times after a given datetime.timedelta?

My current solution is not elegant, I am using something like *df.index.time > t* where *t* is a *datetime.time* object (which in turn needs to be created from a timedelta object).

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with that method

Comment: Depending on what you are doing [`partial string indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing) may be better but I would be surprised if there is a speed difference, I could be wrong of course

Comment: @EdChum: nothing wrong, just not so elegant